# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, make

```
make -C expl
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/expl'
gcc -g -fcommon -w -c ltranslate.lex.c
gcc -g -fcommon -o ltranslate ltranslate.lex.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/expl'
make -C spl
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/spl'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'default'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/spl'
make -C xfs-interface
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/xfs-interface'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'default'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/xfs-interface'
make -C xsm
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/xsm'
cc -g -o xsm lex.yy.o machine.o main.o simulator.o word.o memory.o registers.o tokenize.o disk.o debug.o exception.o '-ll'
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:14: xsm] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hitesh/myexpos/xsm'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

When I try to add library `sudo apt-get install libl-dev` again the error is `Unable to locate package libl-dev`. Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; `libl-dev` doesn't exist in Ubuntu repositories for my release; but you may not be using my release; are you hoping we guess what OS/product/release you're using; why not just tell us.

Answer (score 0):

[libfl-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libfl-dev/filelist) lists `libl`:

```
/usr/include/FlexLexer.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libfl.pc
/usr/share/doc/libfl-dev/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfl-dev/README.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfl-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfl-dev/copyright
```

So the command seems to be

```
sudo apt install libfl-dev
```